# css grid max-width when number of items doesnt fill the page

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have this code that creates even columns using css grid

```css
.grid-container{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(320px, 1fr));
}

.grid-item{
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.grid-item:nth-child(even) {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item">1</div>
  <div class="grid-item">2</div>
  <div class="grid-item">3</div>
  <div class="grid-item">4</div>
  <div class="grid-item">5</div>
  <div class="grid-item">6</div>
  <div class="grid-item">7</div>
</div>
```

now this works until theres only 1 or 2 items like so..

```css
.grid-container{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(320px, 1fr));
}

.grid-item{
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.grid-item:nth-child(even) {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item">1</div>
  <div class="grid-item">2</div>
</div>
```

whats happening is If there are less items than will fill the width of the page, I would like the grid items to have a `max-width: 25%`;

The desired result would be

[image]

I've tried to add

```
.grid-container{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(320px, 25%));
}
```

which does work.. until the screen gets smaller and then the elements no longer wrap at `320px`

```css
.grid-container{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(320px, 25%));
}

.grid-item{
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.grid-item:nth-child(even) {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item">1</div>
  <div class="grid-item">2</div>
</div>
```

Is there anyway I can achieve this??

**EDIT**

I am using javascript to determine how many items are in the grid-container and then dynamically adding a new class to have the new minmax

Comment: Try `auto-fill` instead of `auto-fit`. https://jsfiddle.net/p20jegf3/

Comment: @Michael_B this worked thankyou! could you please post your response as an answer and I will mark it correct?? Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. I've explained this solution in another post. I'll make this a duplicate.

Comment: Else, make ghost containers if you want to keep auto-fit https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/XLKewJ